# What is the purpose of the phrase `if x is an object` in [basic.def.odr]/3?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, one-definition-rule

[[basic.def.odr]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#3):

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   ex is odr-used by ex unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>   (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke
>   any non-trivial functions and, **if x is an object**, ex is an element
>   of the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5). `...`

Why is the additional condition "if x is an object" included in the text above?

Comment: As opposed to reference?

Comment: In addition to references, functions and `void` are the other non-object types.  See http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf for a graphical portrayal of the type classification system.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a variable. But variables don't have to be objects. They can also be references. References are references to objects but the reference itself is *not* an object (unlike pointers which are objects as well as potentially point to an object).

So the statement there is making the distinction between variables that declare objects and variables that declare references to an object.

Comment: So you're basically saying that if x is reference, you don't need to verify the remaining part of the paragraph, to determine whether x is odr-used or not. Is that the idea?

Answer (score 2):

There are two requirements in the text that both have to be fulfilled in order for a variable `x` to *not* be odr-used. Those requirements are:

1. > applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke any non-trivial functions

And

2. > if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5)

The wording is awkward, but the second point is a logical condition: `P --> Q`. Logical conditionals are only false if both `P` is `true` and `Q` is`false`. If `P` is `false`, the conditional is still `true`. In this case, the "if `x` is an object" premise is `false` if `x` is a reference. In that case, the whole requirement evaluates as true.

In other words, if `x` is a reference, it is odr-used unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke any non-trivial functions. That's it. Even if `ex` were a discard-value expression, `x` would still be odr-used if it were a reference.

Comment: Great answer! (+1) `Even if e is a discarded-value expression, x would still be odr-used if it were a reference.` Isn't that weird?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence. In the reference case there's no `e`.

Comment: @T.C. what I mean is that if you have a discarded-value expression with a reference, it's still odr-used. Just emphasizing that that part doesn't apply to references.

Comment: What does discarded-value expression has to do with the reference case? If `x` is a reference, then #2 is trivially satisfied. Note that #1 doesn't require that the expression in which `x` appears *actually* apply l-to-r to `x`.

Comment: But see core issues 2083 and 2103. This text is a mess.

Comment: @T.C. That's what I'm saying, it doesn't. I'm simply providing emphasis. The wording is unnecessarily opaque and I'm trying to explain in multiple ways what #2 means.